# Error activating int No matching bindings are av

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, hangfire.ninject

I am trying to use Hangfire to run a background job in my MVC project.

I call the `Enqueue` method in the constructor of my controller:

```
public SHQSController(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _Uow.CostRepository.Merge());
}
```

The `_Uow.CostRepository` property returns an Interface:

```
public ICostRepository CostRepository
{
    get
    {
       return new CostRepository(_Context, _CurrentOrganisationID);
    }
}
```

But the job fails in hangfire giving the following reason:

> Error activating int No matching bindings are av…

I have found that if I change the code so that the job is called on the implementation of `ICostRepository` instead of via the interface, it works:

i.e. in my controller:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _Uow.Test());
```

and in my unit of work:

```
public void Test()
{
    new CostRepository(_Context, _CurrentOrganisationID).Merge();
}
```

What is going on here? Is there a way to queue a job that allows me to put my implementaion in my repository rather than my unit of work?

**EDIT:** I found the full error message in the HangFire.State table The full error is:

> Error activating int No matching bindings are available,  and the type
>   is not self-bindable. Activation path:    2) Injection of dependency
>   int into parameter currentOrganisationID of constructor of type
>   CostRepository    1) Request for CostRepository  Suggestions:    1)
>   Ensure that you have defined a binding for int.    2) If the binding
>   was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into
>   the kernel.    3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than
>   one kernel.    4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that
>   the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.    5) If
>   you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and
>   filters are correct.

So the problem is the `CurrentOrganisationID` that the `CostRepository` is dependent on. The `CurrentOrganisationID` is currently retrieved from the `HttpContext` and set on the unit of work, which passes it to the repository's constructor as shown in my code above.

Comment: This is a NInject error, isn't it? Can you show the whole error message, as it should include some extra information?

Comment: @stuartd It is a Ninject error. I think it is because the CostRepository takes an integer in the constructor and Hangfire is trying to inject the repository rather than use my explicit call. I'm afraid I don't know how to get the whole message out of hangfire

Comment: @stuartd Found the full error message. It confirms my suspicion. See my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with this line:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _Uow.CostRepository.Merge());
```

is that Hangfire interprets this as a requirement to instantiate an implementation of `ICostRepository` and run its `Merge` method rather than instantiate an implemetation of `IUow` and run `CostRepository.Merge()` on that.

I got around that by creating a public method on the controller:

```
public void Merge(int organisationid)
{
    _Uow.CostRepository.MergeSHQSCostsTable(organisationid);
}
```

and passing that to the `Enqueue` method:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Merge(organisationid));
```

The job queued by Hangfire is now `SHQSController.Merge` and the dependencies are now correctly resolved.

As an aside, you might notice that I now pass the `organisationid` in to the method as a parameter where previously it was available within the repository. This is retrieved from the `HttpContext` and since this isn't available when the controller is instantiated from a background job, I had to create another private method called from the constructor so that the `organisationid` was wired in to the background job:

So, instead of:

```
public SHQSController(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _Uow.CostRepository.Merge(CurrentOrganisationId));
}
```

I have:

```
public SHQSController(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
{
   EnqueueMerge(CurrentOrganisationID);
}

private void EnqueueMerge(int organisationid)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Merge(organisationid));
}
```